# android app automatically link and update results

Tags: android, synchronization

I would like to make a lottery app, in which everytime when there are new numbers (shown in the lottery official website), could the app, when the user clicks the button, be able to update the lottery results by fetching the result from that official website? The app would then refresh showing the most updated results / database automatically (so called synchronization?).

How could this be made? COuld someone give me some direction and some sample / tutorials for this function? and do I need to have a website / host for such data?

Many thanks!!

Comment: push notification([GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)) + REST web service ... and yes, you need to have a web server for storing data

Comment: Since there is an update button, pushing notification with GCM is not a must. Web Service calls when button is pressed should do the work. Web server is needed, as Selvin mentioned

Comment: thanks for both your comments. Slightly modified the question, how about if there is actually already have a official website from the government lottery organization, could the app be able to, when the user presses the relevant update button, then start to directly fetch the result from the website and update the current database? Thanks! (I would like some direction for some necessary components / tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

http://www.recursiveawesome.com/blog/2011/04/29/implementing-pull-to-refresh-in-your-android-app/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I would like to ask if there is actually already have a official website from the government lottery organization, could the app be able to, when the user presses the relevant update button, then start to directly fetch the result from the website and update the current database? Thanks! It would be very happy if there are some direction and suggestions for some necessary components be very great if have tutorials!